# How to Use image as border in an android xml

Tags: android-layout

I have a popup to show in my xml. It should have a border. Following is the code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rl_parent"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="20dp" >
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_startpopup"
    android:layout_width="340dp"
    android:layout_height="320dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/popup_outline"
    android:orientation="vertical" />    
</RelativeLayout>
```

The popup_outline is a shape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:endColor="#192423"
    android:startColor="#4a7669"
    android:type="linear" />
<corners android:radius="8dp" />
<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#e4f4d3" />
</shape>
```

here is the image of the popup:-

[image]

This "popup_outline" is the white border shown. I want to use a repeatable pattern image instead of one color as the border. I have to do this in xml. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use a FrameLayout to show the border and inside FrameLayout use ImageView or RelativeLayout to show other content.

Example:-

```
<FrameLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/IMAGE_OF_YOUR_CHOICE_WITH_repeatable pattern"
        >
        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ></RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any layout to use border and inside the layout you free to use any view or layout e.g TextView, ImageView

Example:-

`<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="@drawable/popupbox"
        android:padding="50dp">
      <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Your Garage is empty" />
</RelativeLayout>`